# Angular change detection does not run with onPush when using a Subject

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mve-trace-multi-filter',
  template: `
    <child [itemsReady]="itemsReady$ | async"></child>
  `
})
    export class ParentComponent {

      itemsReady$ : Subject<any> = new Subject();

      ngOnInit() {
        this.store.select('state').subscribe(data => this.itemsReady$.next(data));
      }

    }
```

And a child component with onPush

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
export class ChildComponent {

    @Input() set itemsReady( items ) {
      console.log('change', items);
    }
  }
```

}

The problem is that when the `next()` method is run, there is not change detection in the child component. I am excepting the child component to be updated because of the async pipe. What is wrong?

I saw the log as null in the first time but that's it.

Comment: Where do you set `teamsReady`? Shouldn't it be `@Input() set items(items)`?

Comment: It should be `items`

Comment: It was a typo...